# Replace a word with another in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

In Eclipse Classic I am developing an android app that has numerous save SharedPreferences and all with the same name of SharedPreference similar to below:

```
SavePreferences("NAME_OF_THE_SHAREDPREFERENCE", ("Some random text"));
```

But I want to change the name of the SharedPreference in another class. This will (if its possible) save me lot of time, instead of changing them one by one.

I know the Ctrl+H comand but I am not able to find the "NAME_OF_THE_SHAREDPREFERENCE", and/or replace it with another name.

Feel free to ask questions if something is hard to understand by my explinations:-)

Comment: Select constant, right mouse click Refactor -> Remane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because these strings are different?

```
NAME_OF_SHAREDPREFERENCE
```

is different from (missing "THE_"):

```
NAME_OF_THE_SHAREDPREFERENCE
```

Ok, that was just a typo... But you can use Find/Replace in each file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

---

I also recommend using a static variable instead of a hard-coded String:

```
class ClassA {
    public static final String SHAREDPREFERENCE_FILENAME = "something";

    ...
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHAREDPREFERENCE_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
}

class ClassB {
    ...
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(ClassA.SHAREDPREFERENCE_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

This way you only have to update one location.

Comment: No the the "NAME_OF_THESHAREDPREFERENCE" is just an example and not my actual string.

Comment: And if you want to change name of variable, you can simply youse Alt + Shift + R :)